# How to access an array object inside handlebars in Ember.js, when the index is dynamic?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to access an object within an array inside handlebars, on Ember.js. I've tried the following combinations:

1 `{{render "input-validation-message" validity.options.[_view.contentIndex]}}`

2 `{{render "input-validation-message" validity.options._view.contentIndex}}`

3 `{{render "input-validation-message" validity.options[_view.contentIndex]}}`

The array is `validity.options` and the index is `_view.contentIndex`, which is the only way I know how to access the index within `{{#each}}` loops on Ember.js.

None of the three methods are passing the object through. Does anyone have a solution?

EDIT:

After some playing around, I found out that the `_view.contentIndex` is not being accessed inside of an {{unless}} or {{if}} block. My code looks a little like this:

```
{{#each modelArray}}
       {{#unless _view.contentIndex}}
        [code here that needs to access _view.contentIndex]
       {{else}}
        [more code here that needs to access _view.contentIndex]
       {{/unless}}
{{/each}}
```

Is there a way to get pass this issue?

---

FIXED!

I modified the correct answer below slightly:

```
{{#each item in modelArray itemController='foo'}}
   {{render "input-validation-message" item.validityOption}}
{{/each}}

App.FooController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  validityOption: function(){
    var model = this.get('model'),
        eachController = this.get('target'),
        parentController = eachController.get('target'),
        idx = eachController.get('content').indexOf(model);
    return parentController.get('validity.options').objectAt(idx);
  }.property('model')
});
```

If the array is not an Ember.Array, use `[]` not `objectAt()`.

Comment: are you eaching over one array and trying to grab options from a different array?

Comment: @kingpin2k Yeah the eaching array is a DS.Model, whereas the validity.options array is a simple array. I've found a more specific reason for the error, please check the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use an itemController and hook up the association in the controller

```
{{#each item in modelArray itemController='foo'}}
   {{render "input-validation-message" item.validityOption}}
{{/each}}

App.FooController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  validityOption: function(){
    var model = this.get('model'),
        parentController = this.parentController,
        idx = parentController.indexOf(model);
    return parentController.get('validity.options').objectAt(idx);
  }.property('model')
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ruzusiya/1/edit

Comment: Excellent! Did not know about the itemController property. I had to modify it slightly, please check the edit.